# ImportError: cannot import name 'softcossim' from 'gensim.matutils' (d:\python\lib\site-packages\gensim\matutils.py)

Tags: python, gensim, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to use the Gensim for soft cosine similarity. I do install gensim using `pip install gensim`. Also, I have upgraded it.

But, still the error is not resolved.

Comment: What command did you use for upgrade and mention version of `gensim` after and before upgradation

Answer (score 0):

Please put your code hear-
I most commonly think that sometimes#

```
import test
test.test()
```

doesn't work and you need

```
from test import *
test()
```